# Is it safe to keep using graphics card with blown diode?

Tags: diodes, gpu

Is it safe to use my GTX 1070 ti with a blown diode? It works as usual. Please see attached image. I don't know much about this, but it looks like d33 has blown.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: D33 is a diode. Where's the capacitor?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I see, then I should rephrase the question. The only issue I see is this d33. I'm just wondering wether it is still safe to use this graphics when this D33 has blown.

Comment: Safe in what sense? Will it burn your building down? or Will it cause more damage? It looks like it might have had something to do with the white SMT LED.  Is that true?

Comment: You'll need to supply the schematic before someone could answer that. What does D33 do?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes, will it burn the building down? Will it cause any damage to the other connected harware? Which white smt led are you asking about? Is it somewhere in this picture?

Comment: Yes, there is a white LED near the upper right corner. And probably some other color of LED above it.

Comment: @fonnes questions like `will it do ....?` cannot be answered ... only questions like `could it do ....?` can be answered

Comment: This is probably an indicator of other problems. Possibly ground loops with the monitors or something like that. That diode is likely there to protect a more expensive component and that protection is now gone. I would replace that part AND try to find the cause. I'm guessing this is not a design flaw that you can ignore. Are you over-clocking? Is that the ASUS board?

Comment: It looks like the ASUS board and that looks like part of the power management circuit... Could be noise on your power supply. How hard are you pushing the supply, i.e. how close to the max rating are you?

Comment: Won't burn your house down.   I'd go ahead and run it until it fails.   Not like this is a control panel for a passenger jet.   If it burns up and fails, worst case you lose that game of Call of Duty

Comment: We don't know what each component does in your circuit. Therefore we don't know how this blown diode will alter the circuit operation. So we don't know if it is safe or not. And it depends on your definition of safe. Most likely it does not electrocute anyone or burn down your house so I'd say it is safe. At most it could damage everything inside your computer and all the peripherals connected to it.

Answer (score 1):

It won't burn your building down. It is extremely unlikely it could damage anything else in the box.

It may or may not continue working, looks like something unimportant (LED display or indicator of some kind) is fried totally (maybe something shorted against the PCB or, less likely, failed internally).

Given the current cost and availability of video cards, I personally would keep using it.

If it is under warranty and you honestly know you didn't damage it then I guess you have a decision to make.